# UIScrollView zoomscale inaccuracy

Tags: uiscrollview, zooming

I am trying to fit an image into a predefined graphical representation of a frame (not a view.frame) using UIZoomView.
For adjusting the zoomscale in a way that the image fits into the desired frame width of 250, the code basically is:

```
float frameWidth=250;
float currentZoomScale=frameWidth/currentImage.size.width;
self.scrollView.zoomScale=currentZoomScale;
```

This works almost fine...almost. My problem is a slight inaccuracy depending on the image width.
For example, an image with a width of 640 will result in a zoomScale of 0.390625.
But the visible image width on the screen will be 1 pixel below 250. With other images of different sizes the algorithm works.

I suspect the reason is that the floating point nature of the division result collides with the integer nature of the actual screen pixels...I mean that the zoomscale should be something like 0.391 or similar (I tried 0.4, which is too big).

My questions:

1. Is the algorithm above the right way
   to get what I want?
2. If yes, is there a way to take the inaccuracy into account, i.e. a better algorithm?

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: is the single pixel inaccuracy such a burden? Most people wouldn't notice a single pixel on either side of an image.

Comment: Yes, because it is clearly visible and more importantly, the next step would be to obtain the visible image portion within that frame.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the division you are using is producing a decimal number and when converted to pixels the decimal number is scrapped because you can't have 0.5 of a pixel. You could automatically round up. Change you algorithm to this:

```
(currentImage.size.width+frameWidth-1)/currentImage.size.width
```

This will give you a whole number rounded up every time.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Daniel! Your explanation is the same as what I tried to explain above, but I knew it was confusing :)

Comment: (5 min limit reached)- Anyway, your solution returns a zoomscale of 1.389063. I think you were thinking of pixels, but I try to tell the zoomView "zoom this image so that the visible image width is 250". With an image width of 640, this will certainly be a number between 0 and 1. I understand that the inaccuracy of my algorithm is unavoidable, hence I am looking for a better solution...

Comment: Do you want to STILL be able to zoom in and out after the initial resize? If not you could literally just adjust the frame width to 250 instead of using zoom scales. Working out the height from this would be easy.

Comment: @marimba - strange thought... finalZoomScale = answer you had -1. This would make 0.389063 which sounds reasonable (no mathematical backing on this, just a thought)

Comment: Yes, I would like to zoom out. currentZoomScale will be the minimum zoom scale as well. 0.389063 is even smaller than 0.390625, but the latter number is already slightly too small.

Comment: Just one note: currentImage.size.width could be anything from several thousand to just a few px, which is why I believe that slightly increasing the zoomScale by a fixed number will not work (i.e., always adding 0.02 to currentZoomScale).